# Php compatibility question

Tags: php

I am trying to run cimyadmin(http://cimyadmin.net/) but i am getting a lot of helper depreciation errors and after looking around the web for answers i am convinced its a php issue.Is there a way to run php 5.0.2 or earlier but not less than php 5 code on latest distributions of php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your php.ini file and look for error_reporting directive, and replace it with this :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Oh,i am new around so am still learning.I tried it and it did not work,at least for the cimyadmn.